# Chrome is not allowed to access my external files?

Tags: css, xampp

Basically I'm going to be working on PHP for my website but I put it all in the htdocs. Now it won't load any of the files including the JavaScript.

This is the css link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Website/CSS/Home.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Relative path: usually absolute path possibility to break or not show output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Home.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick all i had to add was two dots before the CSS part :)